# Yang-Mills mass gap caused by gluonballs or because dark matter WIMPs?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, dark-matter, yang-mills, gluons

Yang-Mills quantum field theory predicts the existence of the lightest massive Bosonic (i.e. integer spin) particle.

This massive Boson will be much lighter than the $W$ and $Z$ Boson and therefore define the mass gap of the re-normalized zero value vacuum energy to the lightest force particle there is.

From what we know from the existing standard model this can be only a composite two gluons particle  which because the gluon color charge interacts via the strong force and acquires mass expected to be in the order of 1.4-1.7 GeV/$c^{2}$ range.

This predicted particles are called [gluonballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball).

My question is, would the Yang-Mills theory be falsified if instead  gluonballs composite particles, a new elementary massive Boson particle was discovered instead, with the lightest mass so far which however could be a chargeless dark matter particle?

In other words, does the YM theory and mass gap also require this predicted lightest non-zero mass Boson particle to be also charged (i.e. color charge)?

Therefore, the mass gap cannot be due to a Bosonic dark matter particle candidate? OR can it?

Comment: I dont see the logical link. If we experimentally find a new particle that is not what the SM predicts, we just have to amend it to add the new physics. It would be an exciting time, and the entire physics community would be celebrating the discovery of new physics. The only way to falsify, is for something that the YM theory actually predicts but is ruled out by experiments. Physicists would also celebrate such an occasion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to believe gluonballs will be different in this respect than any other composite particle; in other words, we have no reason to believe that gluonballs will be dramatically lighter.